# opening html using jquery lightbox

Tags: jquery, html

how to open html page using j-query light box .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend colorbox. It's the best IMO http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

For implementation just use jquery to attach colorbox to a link or other element's click event

e.g.

```
$('#yourlink').colorbox();
```

Make sure the HREF of your link is set to the page you want to open e.g.

```
<a href="yourhtml.html" id="yourlink">Open Lightbox</a>
```

**Update 26/11/2011:**

I'm now using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) instead. It's got a lot of powerful configuration options and works just as well as colorbox.

Comment: I wholeheartedly concur my good sir. Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script you want.

http://jquery.com/demo/grey/

You can download it from

http://jquery.com/demo/grey/greybox.tar

Also these are others

http://www.enthropia.com/labs/ibox/

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open anything other than images with jquery-lightbox (http://www.github.com/krewenki/jquery-lightbox), you can't. I'll second the recommendation for colorbox.